# How do I convert an anonymous function to a symbolic function in MATLAB?

Tags: function, matlab, anonymous-function, symbolic-math

Say I have a anonymous function `f = @(x) x^2` and I want to convert this to a symbolic function. Is there a built in command for that?

Comment: [`func2str`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/func2str.html)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could just pass it to SYM:

```
f = @(x) x^2;
g = sym(f)
```

But then most of the symbolic functions do that automatically when they receive a function handle (`subs`, `int`, etc...)